# ASP.NET - I'm needing a static music player that remains on the page playing no matter if the user navigates away to another page within the site

Tags: c#, asp.net, static, mp3

Hey everyone.. I am needing to have a music player (something like a strip down at the bottom of the page that goes all the way across), that remains at the bottom even when the user navigates to another page within the same site.  The purpose of this is to play music  on the website no matter where the user goes on the website.  Hopefully I'm making sense!

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

The only way to really do what you're looking for is with the use of frames or to load a single page that uses AJAX for all additional content loading.  Anything that causes the page to reload will interrupt playback (a frame can exist as it's own page).

Check out my response on a similar question -- [Webpage navigation with persistance - ASP.NET C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478836/webpage-navigation-with-persistance-asp-net-c/3478917#3478917)

Answer (score 0):

o6tech answer is right, but you can use master page so your player will reflect in each and every page..

here the code which i had used i hope it will work for you too...

use this code in master page....

```
<head>

  <script src="jquery-1.7.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="jquery.jmp3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.4.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="150" height="20"
                codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab">
                <param name="movie" value="singlemp3player.swf?file=sound.mp3&autostart=true&repeatPlay=true&songVolume=30" />
                <param name="wmode" value="transparent"/>
                <embed wmode="transparent" width="150" height="20" src="singlemp3player.swf?file=sound.mp3&autostart=true&repeatPlay=true&songVolume=30"
                    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
   </object>
</body>
```

make sure to set the attribute AutoStart to true..so your player will work on page load..

Let me know if it works with your settings.

Comment: while this will appear on all pages, it will start playing again each time a new page is loaded - this is not what the OP asked for. As o6tech said - the only way to do this will be with frames/iframes or ajax.